# Textbox with a popup in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, textbox, popup

I'd like to build an own control, but therefore I need to know if its possible to combine a Textbox event with a Popup more or less like the Datepicker Control.
Or is there a better way to do this than with a Popup?

Greets

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Sure you could do this.  In fact look at the DatePicker as an example of how you might do that.  I'd imagine your control would be a composite of TextBox, Button and Popup controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the complete source to the Silverlight Toolkit from the [CodePlex Silverlight Toolkit project site](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18804).

And you can get the source and unit tests for the Beta 2 Release 1 controls at [Shawn Burke's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/03/05/silverlight-2-beta-1-controls-available-including-source-and-unit-tests.aspx).

Neither of these may be exactly what you're looking for, but they might get you on the right track.